# PhpStorm won't open Pug file

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pug

I've installed the Pug (Ex-Jade) plugin and added a new file template

[image: What the pug?!]

When creating a new .pug-file, PhpStorm creates a file which I can't open.

I've already followed the instructions on the official page but it didn't help out.

What step did I miss? Any help would be great!

**Edit:**

I have uninstalled the Pug plugin, invalidated the cache and restarted.
Then removed the template i've created because pstorm created a new template called "Pug/Jade File". Then i created a new file from the context menu but again, a file name with a blank icon.

I was curious and opened another project where i've created a .pug file, but same error. So this tells me it has to do with the app itself.

The idea log doesn't show anything which could lead to an answer, but here:

```
    2016-09-23 11:59:57,956 [   2501]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Filesystem storage is corrupted or does not exist. [Re]Building. Reason: Corruption marker file found 
    2016-09-23 11:59:57,960 [   2505]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted: '/Users/morten.sassi/Library/Caches/PhpStorm2016.2/caches/names.dat' does not exist 
    2016-09-23 11:59:57,962 [   2507]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=970 
    2016-09-23 11:59:57,995 [   2540]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,006 [   2551]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,132 [   2677]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,132 [   2677]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   dumb.aware.run.configurations = true 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,459 [   3004]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,820 [   3365]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
    2016-09-23 11:59:58,969 [   3514]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,109 [   3654]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:65 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,113 [   3658]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:3 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,160 [   3705]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:11 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,160 [   3705]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,273 [   3818]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Name storage is repaired 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,277 [   3822]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,617 [   4162]   INFO - ij.psi.stubs.StubUpdatingIndex - Following new file types will be indexed:htaccess,Jade,HTML,SCSS,SQL,TypeScript JSX,CSS,Sass,TypeScript,PHP,JavaScript,JSX Harmony,Less,ActionScript,XML,CoffeeScript,Ini,ECMAScript 6,Literate CoffeeScript 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,816 [   4361]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 85 application components initialized in 2522 ms 
    2016-09-23 11:59:59,846 [   4391]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 5262 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:00:00,255 [   4800]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@3162f833 
    2016-09-23 12:00:00,975 [   5520]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1862 
    2016-09-23 12:00:01,079 [   5624]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@71931992 
    2016-09-23 12:00:01,445 [   5990]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 116 project components initialized in 878 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:00:01,494 [   6039]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 48 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:00:01,727 [   6272]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode 
    2016-09-23 12:00:02,200 [   6745]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:1224 
    2016-09-23 12:00:02,862 [   7407]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 711ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
    2016-09-23 12:00:03,133 [   7678]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - /Users/morten.sassi/www/musterrechnung/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=true actual=true 
    2016-09-23 12:00:03,412 [   7957]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 548ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
    2016-09-23 12:00:03,413 [   7958]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 1178 files to update 
    2016-09-23 12:00:04,947 [   9492]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 4459 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:00:06,053 [  10598]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode EightBitInput is not implemented, setting to true 
    2016-09-23 12:00:18,634 [  23179]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 15221ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 2/16 sluggish 
    2016-09-23 12:00:19,519 [  24064]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - HTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/lib/phpstorm.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5.rnc 
    2016-09-23 12:00:19,519 [  24064]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - XHTML5_SCHEMA_LOCATION = /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/lib/phpstorm.jar!/resources/html5-schema/xhtml5.rnc 
    2016-09-23 12:00:19,519 [  24064]   INFO - tellij.xml.Html5SchemaProvider - CHARS_DTD_LOCATION = /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/lib/phpstorm.jar!/resources/html5-schema/html5chars.ent 
    2016-09-23 12:03:24,297 [ 208842]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 24 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:03:24,308 [ 208853]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:05:19,192 [ 323737]   INFO - llij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl - Failed to load help set from 'jar:file:////Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/help/null!/null/Help.hs' 
    javax.help.HelpSetException: Could not parse
    Got an IOException (/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/help/null (No such file or directory))
    Parsing failed for null
        at javax.help.HelpSet.<init>(HelpSet.java:154)
        at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.a(HelpManagerImpl.java:133)
        at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.a(HelpManagerImpl.java:107)
        at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.invokeHelp(HelpManagerImpl.java:57)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.doHelpAction(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:171)
        at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$HelpAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1894)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.a(IdeEventQueue.java:793)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:625)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:385)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
        at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
        at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
        at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:455)
        at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1665)
        at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1607)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.access$801(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:45)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.a(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:127)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbPermissionServiceImpl.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbPermissionServiceImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbService.java:283)
        at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.show(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:127)
        at com.intellij.ide.actions.EditFileTemplatesAction.actionPerformed(EditFileTemplatesAction.java:31)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.a(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.a(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.a(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.a(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.a(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.a(IdeEventQueue.java:793)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:625)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:385)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    2016-09-23 12:05:35,092 [ 339637]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: editor for id: editor.preferences.import 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,020 [ 360565]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Execution has been finished 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,089 [ 360634]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,089 [ 360634]   INFO - Types.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl - FileTypeManager: 64 auto-detected files
    Elapsed time on auto-detect: 1067 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,093 [ 360638]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,093 [ 360638]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,093 [ 360638]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,126 [ 360671]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,131 [ 360676]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,132 [ 360677]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,145 [ 360690]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,190 [ 360735]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
    2016-09-23 12:05:56,190 [ 360735]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,416 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,438 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PhpStorm (build #PS-162.1889.1, 23 Aug 2016 00:00) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,438 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.11.6, x86_64) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,438 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,438 [     22]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.76-b216 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,444 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xverify:none -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/morten.sassi/java_error_in_phpstorm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/morten.sassi/java_error_in_phpstorm.hprof -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Users/morten.sassi/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.2/phpstorm.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=jdk-bundled -Didea.home.path=/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents -Didea.executable=phpstorm -Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm -Didea.paths.selector=PhpStorm2016.2 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,444 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext: [cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,444 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /System/Library/Java/Extensions: [MRJToolkit.jar] 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,445 [     29]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: UTF-8 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,461 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 16 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,464 [     48]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,465 [     49]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/k6/vcb7qtwd5b98_87mt_1588mr8vdjcy/T/intellij-shell-env.tmp' 
    2016-09-23 12:06:01,472 [     56]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
    2016-09-23 12:06:02,089 [    673]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (30 vars) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,470 [   2054]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,512 [   2096]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor plugin-intelliLang.xml 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,556 [   2140]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-properties-support.xml 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,557 [   2141]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-java-support.xml 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,739 [   2323]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 64 plugins initialized in 406 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,741 [   2325]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), AngularJS (162.1889.1), Apache config (.htaccess) support (162.1889.1), Behat Support (162.1889.1), Blade Support (162.1889.1), CSS Support (162.1889.1), CVS Integration (11), CoffeeScript (2.0), Command Line Tool Support (162.1889.1), Copyright (8.1), Database Tools and SQL (1.0), Drupal Support (162.1889.1), File Watchers (162.1889.1), GNU GetText files support (*.po) (136.SNAPSHOT), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (162.1889.1), Google App Engine Support for PHP (162.1889.1), HAML (162.1889.1), HTML Tools (2.0), IDEA CORE (162.1889.1), Ini4Idea (162.1889.1), IntelliLang (8.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Joomla! Support (162.1889.1), LESS support (162.1889.1), Markdown support (VERSION), NodeJS (162.1889.1), PHP (162.1889.1), PHP Remote Interpreter (162.1889.1), Perforce Integration (2.0), Performance Testing (162.1889.1), Phing Support (162.1889.1), QuirksMode (162.1889.1), REST Client (162.1889.1), ReStructuredText Support (136.SNAPSHOT), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SASS support (162.1889.1), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Settings Repository (162.1889.1), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (VERSION), Time Tracking (1.0), Twig Support (162.1889.1), UML Support (1.0), Vagrant (0.6.VERSION), W3C Validators (2.0), WordPress Support (162.1889.1), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (162.1889.1), hg4idea (10.0) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:03,741 [   2325]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Bootstrap 3 (2.2.1), JS Toolbox (1.9), Laravel Plugin (0.11), LiveEdit (162.1117), Material Theme UI (0.2.1), RegexpTester (1.0.5), Yeoman (162.61) 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,017 [   2601]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=970 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,073 [   2657]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,082 [   2666]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,200 [   2784]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,200 [   2784]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   dumb.aware.run.configurations = true 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,833 [   3417]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
    2016-09-23 12:06:04,985 [   3569]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,106 [   3690]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:32 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,109 [   3693]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:3 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,125 [   3709]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:11 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,125 [   3709]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,277 [   3861]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Version has changed for index TodoIndex. The index will be rebuilt. 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,293 [   3877]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,464 [   4048]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Version has changed for index IdIndex. The index will be rebuilt. 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,681 [   4265]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Version has changed for index filetypes. The index will be rebuilt. 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,863 [   4447]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 85 application components initialized in 2531 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,895 [   4479]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 5257 ms 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,956 [   4540]   INFO - ij.psi.stubs.StubUpdatingIndex - requesting complete stub index rebuild due to changes: removed file types:Jade 
    2016-09-23 12:06:05,956 [   4540]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl -
```

Edit 2:

Reinstalled PHPStorm (Uninstalled via CleanMyMac) but still same error. Somehow the IDE kept all settings and plugins

Comment: Out of curiosity: create a file outside of IDE and then try opening it (in PhpStorm) -- will it work this way? Anything interesting in `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in...)? P.S. Have not worked with pug/jade files myself before)

Comment: Hey @LazyOne , thank your for the edit! 
In the project folder i've created a .pug file in Sublime and saved it but pStorm couldn't open it. Please check out the edit for more infos about this

Answer (score 3):

Okay got the problem!

In: Preferences | Editor | File Types | Jade

there was only *.jade as registered pattern, so adding *.pug did the trick!

I guess i "broke" it initially when creating that file template.